# Do locally trivial and smooth fibrations correspond to subbundles of the tangent bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, fibration

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n$. Let $p:E\rightarrow M$ be a locally trivial smooth fibration. Does this give us a way to construct a subbundle of the tangent bundle $TE$ of the manifold $E$, moreover should the dimension of the subbundle be $n$?

It seems that locally trivial smooth fibrations should be able to give us a non vanishing section. Non vanishing sections allow us to create subbundles of the tangent bundle using frames. But I'm not sure how to get such sections since I don't know anything about the fibres of $E$ as a fibration over $M$.

Comment: For a smooth fibre bundle $F\to E\overset\pi\to M$ the vertical bundle $V\subset TE$ given $\ker(D\pi)$ is always defined. A complementary distribution $H$ (ie $V + H = TE$ and $V\cap H= E\times \{0\}$) is usually _not_ naturally defined. The choice of such a distribution (with some additional properties) is actually the same as a choice of a geometric structure on the manifold $M$, see  the notion of an [Ehresmann connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection) for more details.

Comment: This seems like something along the lines that I need. This gives that $V$ has dimension $dim(E)-dim(M)$, in the case that our fibration is locally trivial?

Comment: Yes, if $V$ is the vertical tangent bundle from s.harp's comment then choosing a metric allows us to construct an isomorphism $TE \cong V \oplus \pi^* TM$, so $rank(V) = rank(TE) - rank(TM) = dim(E) - dim(M)$.

Comment: I don't know what locally trivial means concretely for a fibration, but it sounds like a short way of saying fibre bundle with structure group the diffeomorphisms of the fibre, so yes in that case you have a sub-bundle of dimension $dim(E)-dim(M)$.